# Making the module jdk.incubator.httpclient visible at runtime

Tags: java, maven, bukkit, java-9, maven-shade-plugin

## Question

How can I make the classes from the module `jdk.incubator.httpclient` visible at runtime?

## What I'm Using

Java 9 + Maven + HttpClient `jdk.incubator.http.HttpClient`

## Problems

=> Maven build failing when using `jdk.incubator.HttpClient`. **Fixed** with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446481/java-9-using-incubator-classes-with-maven/47446549?noredirect=1#comment81848803_47446549) thanks to @nullpointer

=> Runtime stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/incubator/http/HttpClient
at com.foo.Bar.Bar.<clinit>(Bar.java:56) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Class.java:374) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.incubator.http.HttpClient
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(java.base@9-Ubuntu/URLClassLoader.java:388) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-Ubuntu/ClassLoader.java:486) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-Ubuntu/ClassLoader.java:419) ~[?:?]
at com.foo.Bar.Bar.<clinit>(Bar.java:56) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Class.java:374) ~[?:?]
```

## Build Section of Pom

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>.</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/resources</directory>

            <includes>
                <include>plugin.yml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>

            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As you can see, I am using the `maven-shade-plugin` for my dependencies, but since `jdk.incubator.http.HttpClient` is part of the JDK it is not included in my jar.

Trying to execute as:

```
 java -jar --add-modules jdk.incubator.httpclient uhc-staging.jar
```

results into the following exception:

> ```
> Error occurred during initialization of VM 
> java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module jdk.incubator.httpclient not found 
> at java.lang.module.Resolver.fail(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Resolver.java:790) 
> at java.lang.module.Resolver.resolveRequires(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Resolver.java:94)
> at java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveRequiresAndUses(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Configuration.java:370)
> at java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor$1.resolveRequiresAndUses(java.base@9-Ubuntu/ModuleDescriptor.java:1986)
> at jdk.internal.module.ModuleBootstrap.boot(java.base@9-Ubuntu/ModuleBootstrap.java:263)
> at java.lang.System.initPhase2(java.base@9-Ubuntu/System.java:1927)
> ```

Comment: @nullpointer The jar is used as an addon. There is a method `enable()` that is called when the main process enables it. To main process is just another jar file started with `java -jar server.jar`

Comment: @nullpointer Sorry for being too brief. My jar is used as a plugin to an api Bukkit. When the Bukkit server starts, it loads all of the plugins, including mine,  and calls the `enable()` method. In my enable method I start by calling to my api with the HttpClient to load some information on user permissions.

Comment: Ideally you should update the question with the integration part of the current jar with Bukkit and the code used in there. [Though, honestly I am not much aware of how Bukkit works.]

Comment: @nullpointer I have found another question that seems to have a similar issue. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129397/noclassdeffounderror-while-trying-to-use-jdk-incubator-http-httpclient-in-java-i). They use `--add-modules jdk.incubator.httpclient` but I am not sure where I would put this with maven. If you know, that would be awesome. I will continue searching as well. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Something fishy here, is there any chance that you are running a really old early access build of JDK 9? What does `java -version` print?

Comment: @AlanBateman In a [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159630/discussion-between-nullpointer-and-caleb-bassham) with OP. Figured out that the `java --list-modules` for the installed JDK doesn't include `jdk.incubator.httpclient`. Suggested to install the latest JDK for Ubuntu. Maybe you can guide better in terms of where to download from or further.

Comment: Thanks for a link to the discussion. He seems to be running with a build of jdk-9+134 so it's an ancient EA build from 2016 and before the incubating feature settled down. Once it install a GA release (9 or the latest 9.0.01) then it will be a lot easier to help him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159630/discussion-between-nullpointer-and-caleb-bassham), the detail brought out was that executing:-

```
java --list-modules
```

doesn't include `jdk.incubator.httpclient` as a module which is the reason why the `j.l.m.ResolutionException` is thrown. Hence, the solution to this shall be upgrading the JDK version installed to the latest release(which should include the incubator module) and then trying to run the application using the same command as suggested:-

```
java -jar --add-modules jdk.incubator.httpclient uhc-staging.jar
```

Comment: To expand on this, I had the `openjdk-9-jdk` package on Ubuntu 16.10, which is no longer a supported version of Ubuntu. Upgrading to 17.04 allowed me to install the `oracle-java9-installer` package which had failed to install with 16.10.

Since the `openjdk-9-jdk` package does not come with the incubator module, using the `--add-modules jdk.incubator.httpclient` would not work.

Using `oracle-java9-installer` and running the jar with `--add-modules jdk.incubator.httpclient` fixed the problem

Comment: Also, to avoid using the `--add-modules` on the command line. One has to [execute using the modulepath as detailed out in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47468106/1746118).